# Excel - Macro to import and replace an existing spreadsheet

Tags: excel, import, replace

I work with an excel document with around 25 sheets, 5 sheets are used to summarize the other 20 sheets.  Every month I get 20 NEW updated sheets that I have to import into this excel document (I can't just copy and paste it since some cells are locked and need to remain that way).

At the moment I just copy individual sheets into the excel document, delete the old ones, and update all the formulas on the 5 summary sheets to reflect these new sheets.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Can you not unlock those cells just for the time of updating the worksheets ?